# When is $E(v|v\geq x)-x$ decreasing in x?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Say v is a random variable with CDF F, I am looking for simple condition on F such that $E(v|v\geq x)-x$ be decreasing in x.  $F''\leq 0$ is sufficient.  But are there more general classes of CDF functions F that do it?

Comment: But a CDF can never have $F'' \le 0$ everywhere...?

Comment: Correct, it would be for x \in [x_0,\infty) for a given x_0